# "SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg" when trying to print values of variables in a Label

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I was just trying to print the values of variables in a `Label` declaration as given below

```
c = Label(root, text="Enter The Number Of Fruits In Basket%d Of Type%d\n"%j,i)
```

but I am getting the below error

> SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Am I missing anything, or declaring any arg wrongly?

Comment: @ParvizKarimli The code provided by the OP is more than enough (in this case at least).

Comment: Your string interpolation is wrong, you forgot using parenthesis, c = Label(root, text="Enter The Number Of Fruits In Basket%d Of Type%d\n" % (j, i))

Comment: Oh.. GOsh.. Silly.. THanks a lot Folks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't used brackets around `j, i` for the format string, Python thinks that `i` is a variable being passed to the `Label()` function as the 3 argument, instead of the format string. And since you've put `text=` (as a named argument) already, then all subsequent args also have to be named.

Add the brackets around `j, i` and then it should be okay:

```
c = Label(root, text="Enter The Number Of Fruits In Basket%d Of Type%d\n" % (j, i))
```

Comment: That was a silly mistake.. Thanks a lot for the clarification !